# Value extraction from Database

Tags: database, excel, extract

Hi i was wonder if there is an automate way to do the follwing:

a. We have an database with part numbers in colum A and corresponding value in Colum B in worksheet xyz (about 5000 entries)

b. I would like to get the value of 10 specific parts by providing the part numbers.

Is there a formula for this kind of extraction in excel ?

Answer (score 1):

This shoould be easy with =VLOOKUP()
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx